# Display Random Grid Row

Tags: grid

I have a channel setup called Testimonials. With each testimonial, the client wants to show one of two supporting accolades (e.g. "Focused, cohesive strategies" or "We listen"). I put these supporting accolades into a grid thinking that I could display them randomly, one per row; however, that is turning out to either not be possible or I can't figure out how to do it.

The problem I see is that there isn't a way to target a row within an entry. There are only two rows per entry, so I assumed I'd be able to setup a conditional to show one or the other, but I don't see a way to target row 1 or row 2. The row_id parameter provides the IDs for all rows in the table (currently 12), not just the rows within the entry. Same for fixed_order.

This is the code I tried, implementing the low_random plugin to set the row variable to either 1 or 2:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage_testimonials" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|pagination" status="open" dynamic="no"}
    <div class="slide">
        {if {random_row} == 1}
            <div class="animate-text">{home_accolades row_id="1"}<span>{home_accolades:accolade}</span>{/home_accolades}</div>
        {if:else}
            <div class="animate-text">{home_accolades row_id="2"}<span>{home_accolades:accolade}</span>{/home_accolades}</div>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So my question is, is it possible to display a random grid row?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing to generate `{random_row}`.

If you have Low Random installed you could try something like this...

HTH

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage_testimonials" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|pagination" status="open" dynamic="no"}
    <div class="slide">
        {if {exp:low_random:item items="cat|dog"} == "cat"}
            <div class="animate-text">{home_accolades row_id="1"}<span>{home_accolades:accolade}</span>{/home_accolades}</div>
        {if:else}
            <div class="animate-text">{home_accolades row_id="2"}<span>{home_accolades:accolade}</span>{/home_accolades}</div>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing I'm doing. I had put Low Random in a snippet is the only difference I see. The problem still is that the row_id parameter doesn't match the rows within the entry. Anyway, I abandoned the Grid field for this and went a different route.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried {home_accolades orderby="random"} instead of {home_accolades row_id="1"}?